# Embedding Excel as an Image Object into Word Document. Coldfusion

Tags: excel, coldfusion, ms-word, embed, coldfusion-10

Have anyone tried to embed excel as an image object to a word document using coldfusion? I have found no reference or tutorial to the question above so far on the internet. My code as of now does nothing to embed and would like someone who can share a link related to the question. Quick reference:

```
<!-- strPath is cffile.serverFile of cffile action="upload" -->
<cfset strpa = session.yo.path />
<cfif not structKeyExists(session, "yo")>
<cflocation url="form.cfm" addToken="false">
</cfif>

<head>
</head>
<body>
    <CFOUTPUT>
        Excel Table: </br>
        <cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#GetTempDirectory()##strpa#" query="Result"> <cfdump var="#Result#"></br>
        TextLabel: #session.yo.text#    </br>

        <!-- Embed Excel as Image Object to Word Document here?-->

    </CFOUTPUT>
<a class="word-export" href="javascript:void(0)">Save As doc for the web page with wordexport.js lib </a> 
</div>

<script src="js/FileSaver.js"></script> 

<script src="js/jquery.wordexport.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("a.word-export").click(function(event) {
            $("#page-content").wordExport();
        });
    });

    </script>

</body>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is two-part task, yes? 1) convert the Excel doc to an image; 2) insert the image into a Word doc. Is it both parts you're having trouble with, or just one?

Comment: @AdamCameron Yes. I'm having trouble with the full process (both parts). I need someone's help on this.

Comment: @AdamCameron but the excel embedded in word document is not an image. It's a image object to open the stored excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the excel embedded in word document is not an image. It's a image
>   object to open the stored excel file

So your real goal is to embed an Excel file, not just an image of it, correct? If so, it is not possible with [the plugin you are using](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Export-Html-To-Word-Document-With-Images-Using-jQuery-Word-Export-Plugin.html). The reason is the plugin simply generates HTML code, which MS Word can interpret. You cannot embed Excel files within an HTML page. To embed a file, you need to generate a real [Word document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word#File_formats) instead, which is not a trivial task.

If you are limited to HTML only, probably the closest you can get is to create a hyperlink to an Excel file. The link could point to a remote file on the server OR to a local file. For example, if you were to use `<a href="ExcelFile.xls">`, MS Word would attempt to open a file named "ExcelFile.xls", located in the same directory as your faux Word document.

Obviously that approach requires exporting both files. Since HTTP requests can only return a single mime type, you would need to create a zip file (containing both the HTML and Excel documents) and return the .zip file instead of .doc.